'Windows Media Player'と連携するオーディオプレイヤーが時々、音声再生終了後、停止、クラッシュする
mp3やwavのオーディオファイルを再生するためにWindows Media Playerを接続するアプリケーションを開発しているのですが、オーディオを再生し終わると停止してしまい、オーディオプレーヤーがクラッシュします。
特定の条件下で発生していると考えていますが、原因がわからず、困っています。
似たような事象が発生したことがある方や、原因の詳細がわかる方、お教えいただけますと嬉しいです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

エラーの詳細
私のオーディオプレイヤーは、おおよそ15秒ごとに起動し、音声再生終了後、プログラムが終了するように、別のプログラムによってスケジューリングされています。複数が同時に起動することはありません。
このオーディオプレイヤーをいくつかのコンピュータにインストールしていますが、 Windows 10 IoT Enterprise LTSC では発生せず、他のPCで発生することがわかっています。
オーディオプレイヤーのログファイルによると、処理をすべて実行し終わった後に10～20秒程度の停止が発生していることがわかっています。
Program Flowchart on the issue
Application Crash Reportの0xc0000409は stack buffer overrunを意味します。
Crash Dumpではwmp.dllが大量に呼ばれている箇所があり、stack buffer overrunが発生しているものと思われます。
Environment



Name
Value




OS
Windows 10 Pro


Processor
Intel® Core™ i5-11500 @2.7Ghz-4.6GHz


RAM
16GB


System
64bit Operating System, x64 base processor


Windows Version
21H2 19044.1706


Library
WMPLib.dll



その他の理由により、Windows版のバージョンは更新しておらず、非推奨のライブラリ： WMPLib.dll を使用しています。
Windowsのバージョンが関係しているということでしたら、ご指摘ください。
Application Crash Report



Name
Value




Fault Module Name
ucrtbase.dll


Fault Module Version
10.0.19041.789


Fault Module Timestamp
0x82dc99a2


Exception Code
0xc0000409


Exception Offset
0x0009eddb



Crash Dump
05d1e624 770ae77d     770ae760 7708189f 93d3a3dc ucrtbase!abort+0x4b
05d1e664 7708189f     93d3a3dc 00920dc8 6ee6e940 ucrtbase!_purecall+0x1d
05d1e664 6ef7969d     00920dc8 00920dcc 00000004 ucrtbase!__crt_state_management::wrapped_invoke<int (__cdecl*)(void),int>+0x9f
WARNING: Stack unwind information not available. Following frames may be wrong.
05d1e678 6ed50bd5     00920dcc 00000000 00000113 wmp!Ordinal3002+0x5f0ed
05d1e690 6ed5097d     00000004 05d1e6c8 771b0fcb wmp+0x140bd5
05d1e69c 771b0fcb     69aa03d8 00000113 00000004 wmp+0x14097d
05d1e6c8 771a3c02     6ed50970 69aa03d8 00000113 user32!_InternalCallWinProc+0x2b
05d1e794 771a5db3     6ed50970 00000000 00000113 user32!UserCallWinProc+0x143
05d1e800 771a5ac0     ae310000 05d1e850 6eda8f83 user32!DispatchMessageWorker+0x2e3
05d1e80c 6eda8f83     05d1e824 6f3deec8 05def858 user32!DispatchMessageW+0x10

05d1e850 6eda8cc5     6eda8cb0 05d1e878 6eda89aa wmp+0x198f83
...(SO MANY calling wmp about 20 TIMES!!!)
05d1ec74 75f31bf5     05d56930 05d1ecf0 05d1ed0c wmp+0x1f5f90

05d1ec98 75e92901     3a9385ec 05d1ecf0 05d1ed0c combase!<lambda_59f7b8acab183cdd0bcc7c9cde5da55a>::operator()+0xab
05d1ecd4 75e928d3     05d9fca8 05d9fca8 05d56930 combase!ObjectMethodExceptionHandlingAction<<lambda_59f7b8acab183cdd0bcc7c9cde5da55a> >+0x1b
05d1ed34 75f31748     00000001 00000040 008868a0 combase!CStdIdentity::ReleaseCtrlUnk+0x77
05d1ed78 75eee40a     00000001 05d1ee00 00000000 combase!CStdMarshal::DisconnectWorker_ReleasesLock+0x409
05d1edac 75eec7c1     00000001 05d1eee4 05d1f11c combase!CStdMarshal::Disconnect+0xba
05d1eecc 75f14715     00000001 05e04e98 00000001 combase!CRemoteUnknown::RemReleaseWorker+0x7e1
05d1eee0 75630ba8     008fdcd8 00000001 05e04e98 combase!CRemoteUnknown::RemRelease+0x15
05d1ef00 755f4de2     75f14700 05d1f120 00000003 rpcrt4!Invoke+0x34
05d1f33c 75e73cd2     00903bb0 008ca2c0 00913624 rpcrt4!NdrStubCall2+0x392
05d1f384 75e73ac3     00903bb0 00913624 008ca2c0 combase!CStdStubBuffer_Invoke+0x92
05d1f3d8 75e73576     00903bb0 00913624 008ca2c0 combase!ObjectMethodExceptionHandlingAction<<lambda_ee1df801181086a03fa4f8f75bd5617f> >+0x6f
05d1f4bc 75ef5921     008ca2c0 00903bb0 05d1f7bc combase!DefaultStubInvoke+0x2b6
05d1f708 75e7b74a     00913624 00903bb0 008ca2c0 combase!ServerCall::ContextInvoke+0x471
05d1f744 75ef81ad     00913624 00000001 00000000 combase!ReentrantSTAInvokeInApartment+0x16a
05d1f9cc 75eabe62     05d1f9eb 00000400 1a6903e8 combase!ComInvokeWithLockAndIPID+0x191d
05d1fa64 771b0fcb     1a6903e8 00000400 0000babe combase!ThreadWndProc+0x452
05d1fa90 771a7f9a     75eaba10 1a6903e8 00000400 user32!_InternalCallWinProc+0x2b
05d1fb74 771a5cfa     75eaba10 00000000 00000400 user32!UserCallWinProcCheckWow+0x33a
05d1fbe8 771a5ac0     00000300 05d1fc30 75e6b1f0 user32!DispatchMessageWorker+0x22a
05d1fbf4 75e6b1f0     05d1fc14 00000000 008868a0 user32!DispatchMessageW+0x10
05d1fc30 75e6b127     75e6b060 00903a70 00000000 combase!CDllHost::STAWorkerLoop+0x86
05d1fc50 75e6b06e     75e6b060 05d1fc88 75ea038e combase!CDllHost::WorkerThread+0xb4
05d1fc5c 75ea038e     7602fe18 00903a70 75f1abf0 combase!DLLHostThreadEntry+0xe
05d1fc88 75f1ac0f     75f1abf0 75f1abf0 05d1fca8 combase!CRpcThread::WorkerLoop+0x198
05d1fc98 76c8fa29     00903a70 76c8fa10 05d1fd04 combase!CRpcThreadCache::RpcWorkerThreadEntry+0x1f
05d1fca8 776d7a7e     00903a70 ebec9ed1 00000000 kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x19
05d1fd04 776d7a4e     ffffffff 776f89fd 00000000 ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+0x2f
05d1fd14 00000000     00000000 00000000 00000000 ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+0x1b

予想される原因
クラッシュダンプによると、RPCスレッドで「スタックバッファオーバーラン」が発生しています。
WMPLibのMediaPlayerクラスはCOMとRPC接続を使用しているため、クラッシュダンプはCOMとWindows Media Playerの連携で問題が発生していることを示しています。
Web上の報告によると、wmplayer.exe は Windows 10 Home でも同様のエラーが発生しているようです。
これらを総合して、WMPLib の MediaPlayer クラスを持つ Windows Media Player を Windows 10 Pro や Home で使用した場合に発生するものと考えています。

Crash Dump に対して下記コマンドを実行し、その出力結果をコピペしてもらえますか？
!analyze -v
lml
!peb
lmDv
~*kvn
なおコピペする際は、出力結果に対して勝手に内容を削除しないでください。
(開発中のモジュール名を公開したくないのであれば、そこだけ伏字にしてから張り付けてください。)
